# For how long do you need to press the buttons when the game tells you to "Hold"?

Tags: project-diva-future-tone

On Future Tone, the game tells you to "Hold" a specific number of buttons to complete a combo or just a single one to mark it as valid.

For how long do you need to press the button(s)?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

General depends on how long you keep, because you get bonus points for it and you can do various combinations. It seems to me that the description of [this topic on the PSN Profiles forum](https://forum.psnprofiles.com/topic/44461-tips-and-tricks/) (section 4. Hold Switching) will clarify your question.